# Creating an interactive bar chart using ggplot and Rshiny

Tags: r

First time asking a question on Stack Overflow

I am having trouble creating a bar plot which I hope to be able to filter based on certain fields. I am using some sensitive data, but I will try to be as clear as possible with the type of data I am using. The data is set up in a hierarchy of sorts, for example the data is as such:

Project -> Subproject -> Sub-SubProject, and a value for each month (jan, feb, march, etc), for a total of 15 columns.

Each row in the csv has a value for each element, so the Project column has a lot of repeated values since it's the top of the hierarchy, with subproject having a fair bit of repeated values as well since it's one level lower.

My goal is to create a bar chart that groups each unique value in the hierarchy, while having the months on the x axis, and values for the months on the y.

So all the values with the same Project, Subproject, will be grouped together, showing the months on the x axis.

I have tried using the ggplot2 library to try to group the values based on hierarchy, but it doesn't look the best and it's aggregating the values rather than showing a the unique value for the entry.

```r
plot <- ggplot(data=data, aes(x= Sub-Project, y = January, fill = Sub-SubProject)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") + 
  facet_grid(~Project, scales = "free_x", space = "free") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=Capacity.1),hjust=0, vjust=0)
```

I want to avoid using fill, since I would like to conditionally set the color on my own, but that is a problem for another time. I was able to somewhat replicate what I am looking for on Tableau, but now the deliverable must be in R.

In general, I would like no aggregation, but a unique bar for each entry, grouped by the hierarchy I said above.